# Keeping the input provided to a generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

Assume I have a generator `gen` that produces items, and another generator `trans` that transforms the items and returns one output item per input item, and assume that both generators are expensive and I can't change either of them. Both generators may have additional arguments. The output of `gen` is fed into `trans`, but when looping over the results of `trans`, I need the corresponding output of `gen` as well. My current solution is to `tee(gen())` and then `zip` that with the output of `trans`, and this works well, but my question is whether there is maybe a better solution that I am missing?

```py
from itertools import tee

# these two generators are just an example, assume these are expensive and can't be changed
def gen():
    yield from range(3)
def trans(inp):
    for x in inp:
        yield chr(x + ord("A"))

# my question is: is there a better way to achieve what the following two lines are doing?
g1, g2 = tee(gen())
for i, o in zip(g1, trans(g2)):
    print(f"{i} -> {o}")
```

Comment: Yours is reasonably nice. Is there anything special you don't like about your approach?

Comment: @S.B Thanks! Since I started learning Python a little over a year ago, I felt like maybe I was missing some obvious solution, like a `map` for generators or something. (Another thing I wondered was whether `trans` should have been better implemented with generator `.send()` instead.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good use case for `tee`. The only downside I see is that it keeps the last up to 57 items in alive, even when you consume the `tee` iterators in parallel. That's because `tee` is rather **speed**-optimized, for **inexpensive** input iterators (see the discussion at the bottom of this answer).

If your items are large, then that can become a memory problem, and the memory problem can also become a speed problem (exhausting your cache or even having to swap to hard drive). Or it could be a problem if your objects are something like file handles that are kept open as long as they're alive.

You could avoid that by sending your input data through an extra generator that stores the current input item as a side effect. Two possible ways:

```
for o in trans(i := x for x in gen()):
    print(f"{i} -> {o}")
```

```
def side_store():
    global i
    for i in gen():
        yield i
for o in trans(side_store()):
    print(f"{i} -> {o}")
```

Demo with an input generator yielding 1 MB large objects:

```
def gen():
    for _ in range(100):
        yield bytes(10**6)

def trans(inp):
    for x in inp:
        yield len(x)
```

Peak memory usage by your method and my two:

```
58,003,398 bytes  original
 2,000,494 bytes  Stefan1
 2,000,678 bytes  Stefan2
```

Test script ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lVTNjtMwEL5wylOMeqld0qrJSghFWiQeAC4gLiyKvM0ktRTbke2KhKpPwmUv8FA8Df5JtqHaslqf0vE333zzzdQ_f3eD3Sv58PDrYOv12z-vvtRaCeAWtVWqNcBFp7QFi5hMn5rtULC2VTtgBqxIkqTCGpTmDZesJQ3K1KOkSWHPZNUiLRJwp8lSaHK49WweRSgN8Vpp4Cko4BJ-8I54XMgnTU7HXH8iGfFQGmt-slgzmV0v6akDb-TjUNxCH6K9j0YRz1fIr1fgrp-PSmL44TMMr7A0VmkkM2appDOMtcAfQ6HtRxVnqD8Dx7YasRc9zPmvSq8Pcmecsmko6WTV9JG7qXWaS0uWH1AoPawtGstlA9-53cM9b_wSCFMsRyNmIr2g0gtyehok2XY70xGV3w-Ozt2sVm9oSB_9l92MI4zAhS6TW1eqj2nzriKsY8YkPrv22bHPFeTx0oqNsUxbMi7WU2MLNyL07FdRbBq0ZVjqqoxhQr9m3858qhvpol_18hhhRbZNT7FTWKZQb8pSMoFlSc_e3snPc1sHddCAPRNdi95R1MwN0hR38gmboxnh_xiNvnm5lbu9Jj28dntQkcX7Bb3qamxtceQnWL-Dozot6IXL_wBnvf7f6Iin8XkZX5nptfkL)):

```py
from itertools import tee
import tracemalloc as tm


def original(gen, trans, handle):
    g1, g2 = tee(gen())
    for i, o in zip(g1, trans(g2)):
        handle(i, o)

def Stefan1(gen, trans, handle):
    for o in trans(i := x for x in gen()):
        handle(i, o)

def Stefan2(gen, trans, handle):
    i = None
    def side_store():
        nonlocal i
        for i in gen():
            yield i
    for o in trans(side_store()):
        handle(i, o)

funcs = original, Stefan1, Stefan2


print('Memory-testing with big items:')

def gen():
    for _ in range(100):
        yield bytes(10**6)
def trans(inp):
    for x in inp:
        yield len(x)
def handle(i, o):
    pass
for f in funcs * 2:
    tm.start()
    f(gen, trans, handle)
    memory = tm.get_traced_memory()[1]
    tm.stop()
    print(f'{memory:10,} bytes ', f.__name__)


print('\nTesting with your example generators:\n')

def gen():
    yield from range(3)
def trans(inp):
    for x in inp:
        yield chr(x + ord("A"))
def handle(i, o):
    print(f"{i} -> {o}")
for f in funcs:
    print(f.__name__)
    f(gen, trans, handle)
    print()
```

The [`tee` source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2f630e1ce18ad2e07428296532a68b11dc66ad10/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L696-L706) discussing its data links holding 57 items (it holds the items in a linked list of "links" each holding not just one but 57 items):

```c
/* The teedataobject pre-allocates space for LINKCELLS number of objects.
   To help the object fit neatly inside cache lines (space for 16 to 32
   pointers), the value should be a multiple of 16 minus  space for
   the other structure members including PyHEAD overhead.  The larger the
   value, the less memory overhead per object and the less time spent
   allocating/deallocating new links.  The smaller the number, the less
   wasted space and the more rapid freeing of older data.
*/
#define LINKCELLS 57
```

Comment: `for o in trans(i := x for x in gen())` is perfect for my application, thank you very much! Luckily, in my current case the items are not large, but the information on tee holding extra items is very good to know, thank you!